# Real and Imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers

$$Re\Big(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i})^4\Big)} = 2$$

$$Im\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = 1$$

I got that $Re\Big(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i})^4\Big)} = 1 \ne 2$

And, that $\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = i $ , which means that $Im\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = 1$

Can you guys confirm that it's true? Thanks in advance!

In this [**image**](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/q83/s720x720/10252035_10152425249402915_4542436710338370870_n.jpg) I got to$(\frac{1−\sqrt3+i+i\sqrt3}{2})^4$ and then, I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: $r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}  = r\left[\cos\theta +i\sin\theta\right]$ and compare terms.

Comment: Because no1 helped me, I opened a new one.

Comment: @Chinny84 I can't do that. you can't find the angle and you can't find the r

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, it is considered improper here to repost your question just because you didn't like the outcome the first time.  You should edit your first question, and wait.

Comment: Oh no! Nobody posted an answer for two whole hours, so you posted the question again? How inconsiderate of us... :|

Comment: Yes you can, you can use $r=0.5$ and you should be able to determine an expression for $\tan \theta$  In terms of the real and imaginary component of the term in the bracket. I apologise that I didn't explain that we are using only the terms in the bracket, for which we can then raise to the 4th power.

Comment: For the question number 2
\begin{align}
\text{Im}\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^5&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\cdot \frac{1+i}{1+i}\right)^5\\
&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{(1+i)^2}{1^2-i^2}\right)^5\\
&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{1+2i+i^2}{2}\right)^5\\
&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{2i}{2}\right)^5\\
\end{align}

Comment: I managed to get to that @V-Moy, as you can see in the image that I've added in my post. but I couldn't get to 2 in the first question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: to be fair, he posted the duplicate to meta and it was migrated here >8( I didn't know about the previous post before I came up for air after answering.

Comment: It's easy Sir. I'll give you a hint:
$$
1+\sqrt{3}i=2e^{\Large\frac{\pi}{3}i}
$$
and
$$
1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{-\Large\frac{\pi}{4}i}
$$
It's not difficult to find the $\text{abs}(z)$ and $\arg(z)$. Check Wiki. I hope this helps you. (ô‿ô)

Comment: Mr. @robjohn, for me it's not fair since I can't post my answer. (╥﹏╥)

Comment: Still didn't get it.

Comment: How did u go from $ 1 + \sqrt3*i =$ to $2e^/sqrt pai/3*i$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Are you kidding me? How come you learn complex number without knowing that thing?? If $z=x+iy$, then it can also be written as:
$$
z=re^{i\theta}
$$
where $r=\text{abs}(z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arg(z)=\arctan\left(\cfrac{y}{x}\right)$. Check Wiki or you can google about complex number for more detail explanation.

Comment: @V-Moy: sorry about that. I answered before it was closed.

Comment: Mr. @robjohn: It's okay Sir. It's not your fault, no need to say sorry to me. ヅ

Comment: @robjohn you should either move your answer (and other's comment) to the other question and hard delete this question or reopen this and hard delete the other question.

Comment: @achillehui: I answered this question as how to compute $$\mathrm{Re}\left[\, \left(\frac{1-\sqrt3+i+i\sqrt3}2\right)^{\large4} \,\right]$$ I had not seen the original question (the one showing no work) before I answered this one, but nonetheless, to me, this is a different question than the other question, and my answer would not make sense as an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Brute force works:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{16}\mathrm{Re}\left[((1-\sqrt3)+i(1+\sqrt3))^4\right]\tag{1}\\
&=\frac1{16}\left(\color{#C00000}{(1-\sqrt3)^4}-\color{#00A000}{6(1-\sqrt3)^2(1+\sqrt3)^2}+\color{#C00000}{(1+\sqrt3)^4}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{16}\left(\color{#C00000}{2(1+6\cdot3+9)}-\color{#00A000}{6(-2)^2}\right)\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=2\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where we have used the binomial theorem a few times
$$
(x+y)^4=x^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4\tag{5}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: copy problem
$(2)$: expand using $(5)$ and drop the terms with an $i$
$(3)$: expand the red terms using $(5)$ and drop the odd exponents ($-\sqrt3$ will cancel $+\sqrt3$)
$(3)$: also use that $(1-\sqrt3)(1+\sqrt3)=1-3=-2$
$(4)$: arithmetic

Comment: How did u get $\frac{1}{16}$? Actually, didn't understand anything. Feeling stupid.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Sir, it's $2^4$ in the denominator. (─‿‿─)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: I have added some explanation that may help.

Comment: How did u get (1)?

Comment: Whats what I did: [link](https://scontent-a-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10155946_459428150826874_6969747818414687259_n.jpg)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: I copied $(1)$ from the point where you said you got $\left(\frac{1−\sqrt3+i+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)^4$ but didn't know how to proceed.

Comment: Well,l you go way far @robjohn. But thx!